# How can I create a glossary as I go?

Tags: glossaries

I'd like to keep defining terms as I go through the document using the description environment, but then have all those terms gathered together (with their descriptions) in a glossary at the end of the document.

The glossaries package would seem to be the obvious choice for how to do this, but I can't see a way to list the entry descriptions in the document body as I go. 
An MWE would look like

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage{blindtext} 
\begin{document} 
\tableofcontents{} 
\section{Introduction}
    \begin{description}
    \item[Ontology] refers to a theory of what is real
    \item[Epistemology] refers to a theory of knowledge
    \end{description}
     \section{Theory} \begin{description}
    \item[Potato] is a class of root vegetables
    \item[Reductionism] refers to the practice of reducing one set of ideas to another \end{description}

\section{Glossary of Terms}

\begin{description}
    \item[Epistemology] refers to a theory of knowledge
    \item[Ontology] refers to a theory of what is real
    \item[Potato] is a class of root vegetables
    \item[Reductionism] refers to the practice of reducing one set of ideas to another \end{description}

\end{document}
```

Which looks this:
[image]

As in, all the terms from the {description} environment get collected, alphabetised, and reproduced with their descriptions in a glossary of terms.

Comment: Could you please show us a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228)?

Comment: I don't recommend redefining the `description` environment because it's sometimes used internally by other environments, so it could have undesirable side-effects.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The simplest method is to create a new file that contains the definitions. This makes it easier to add new terms while you're writing the document as most text editors allow more than one file open at a time, so you can simply switch to the definitions file without losing your place in the document.

Here's `definitions.tex`:

```
\newglossaryentry{ontology}{name={ontology},
  description={refers to a theory of what is real}}
\newglossaryentry{epistemology}{name={epistemology},
 description={refers to a theory of knowledge}}
\newglossaryentry{potato}{name={potato},
 category={theory},
 description={is a class of root vegetables}}
\newglossaryentry{reductionism}{name={reductionism},
 category={theory},
 description={refers to the practice of reducing one set
 of ideas to another}}
```

If your definitions span multiple paragraphs then use `\longnewglossaryentry` instead:

```
\longnewglossaryentry{reductionism}{name={reductionism},category={theory}}
{refers to the practice of reducing one set
 of ideas to another}
```

Here's a document that uses the all the provided definitions:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{glossaries-extra}

\loadglsentries{definitions}

\glssetcategoryattribute{general}{glossname}{firstuc}
\glssetcategoryattribute{theory}{glossname}{firstuc}

\newcommand{\printcategory}[1]{%
  \printunsrtglossary*{%
    \renewcommand{\glossarysection}[2][]{}%
    \renewcommand{\printunsrtglossaryhandler}[1]{%
      \glsifcategory{##1}{#1}{\glsxtrunsrtdo{##1}}{}%
    }%
  }%
}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\section{Introduction}
\printcategory{general}

\section{Theory}
\printcategory{theory}

\printunsrtglossary[title={Glossary of Terms}]

\end{document}
```

If the document is called `myDoc.tex` then the document build is simply:

```
pdflatex myDoc
```

[image: image of document]

This lists all defined terms in the glossary in the order of definition. If you want the list sorted, then it's more complicated.

Here's an alternative method. Save the definitions in a `.bib` file, say, `definitions.bib`:

```
% Encoding: UTF-8
@entry{ontology,
  name = {ontology},
  description = {refers to a theory of what is real}
}

@entry{epistemology,
  name = {epistemology},
  description = {refers to a theory of knowledge}
}

@entry{potato,
  name = {potato},
  plural = {potatoes},
  description = {is a class of root vegetables}
}

@entry{reductionism,
  name = {reductionism},
  description = {refers to the practice of reducing one set
 of ideas to another}
}
```

Again, it should be simple to switch back and forth between two windows without losing your place in the document. The document is now:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[record,% using bib2gls
  postpunc=dot% put a full-stop after the descriptions in the glossary
]{glossaries-extra}

\GlsXtrLoadResources[
  src={definitions},% entries in definitions.bib
  name-case-change={firstuc}% convert the first character of `name` to uppercase and set `text` to the original value of `name`
]

\newcommand{\glossitem}[1]{\item[\glsentryname{#1}]
 \glsadd{#1}\glsentrydesc{#1}.}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\section{Introduction}
\begin{description}
\glossitem{epistemology}
\glossitem{ontology}
\end{description}

\section{Theory}
\begin{description}
\glossitem{potato}
\glossitem{reductionism}
\end{description}

\printunsrtglossary[title={Glossary of Terms}]

\end{document}
```

This gives you more manual control over the ordering within the document for the different sections. The main glossary is now sorted and includes locations in the glossary that indicate where the term was used (page 1 in all cases for this trivial document).

[image: image of document]

The build process is now:

```
pdflatex myDoc
bib2gls myDoc
pdflatex myDoc
```

If you don't want the locations, either use the resource option `save-locations=false`:

```
\GlsXtrLoadResources[
  src={definitions},% entries in definitions.bib
  name-case-change={firstuc},
  save-locations=false
]
```

or use `nonumberlist`:

```
\printunsrtglossary[title={Glossary of Terms},nonumberlist]
```

By default `bib2gls` will sort according to the document language (if detected) otherwise it will sort according to the default locale. You can specify a particular language. For example:

```
\GlsXtrLoadResources[
  src={definitions},% entries in definitions.bib
  name-case-change={firstuc},
  sort={en-GB}
]
```

If you want to reference a term anywhere else in the document, you can use `\gls{`*label*`}`, for example `\gls{ontology}`, or at the start of a sentence `\Gls`, for example `\Gls{potato}`. The plural can be obtained with `\glspl` and `\Glspl`. If you load `hyperref` (before `glossaries-extra`), then these will be turned into hyperlinks to the relevant line in the main glossary.

Comment: These solutions are fantastic, especially the second one. Absolutely excellent!

Comment: @DanGoldwater Glad it's useful. I added a little note about `\gls` just in case.

Comment: I'm having a bit of trouble implementing the second solution here. I get two problems - one that 'postpunc' is an unknown option for glossaries, and one warning 'Package glossaries-extra Warning No File (path, line 28): 'output.glstex' on input line number 28'. 
After a bit of research I would have assumed that I need to update my glossaries-extra package, but I'm writing this on ShareLatex and I can't imagine that they don't keep their packages up to date. Any ideas?

Comment: @DanGoldwater The `postpunc` option was introduced in `glossaries-extra` v1.23 (2017-11-12), so check the log file for the version number. (For older versions you can use just `postdot` instead or  `nopostdot=false` for even older versions.) The `.glstex` file is created by `bib2gls`. Did `bib2gls` run correctly? I'm not sure if ShareLaTeX has `bib2gls` installed. The first stable version was only released on 2017-09-09.

Comment: I asked ShareLatex and got the following response from them, which I post in case it's helpful to others in the future.

Comment: "ShareLaTeX tracks TeXLive Stable, in order to prevent package conflicts, so it is not possible to update the glossaries-extra package individually out of turn. However, you can use more recent package versions by downloading the package's .sty file from CTAN and uploading it to the project on ShareLaTeX. 
Since bib2gls runs a java script to create other files, it is not possible to use it with the editor on ShareLaTeX (which just runs LaTeX compilers directly). But you can use the package by running bib2gls on the command line on your own computer then uploading the files to ShareLaTeX."

Comment: @DanGoldwater ShareLaTeX does run `makeindex` and `bibtex` (I don't know about `xindy` or `biber`), but presumably they either don't want to incorporate a new command line application until it's more established or they don't want to support Java applications (or both). That's unfortunately one of the drawbacks of using an online editor.